# Jquery: How to disable mouseleave function when open new windows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I use this script to show popup tho people who want to quit my website. However, my website has some banner. When clicking banner, the new window browser will be opened, so the popup will appear. So, how to disable mouseleave function when open new windows ?

Jquery: How to disable mouseleave function when open new windows ?

```
$(document).bind('mouseleave', function(event) {
       window.location.href = "http://your-website.com";
});
```

Comment: Try checking out the unbind function: http://api.jquery.com/unbind/ you can use it to "disable" your mouse leave function.

Comment: try windows instead of document

Comment: @Mohit.Bhasi, Hi, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You are using the bind method to bind to an event. Similarly you can use the unbind to revoke the event binding.

Sample Code:

```
var handler = function() {
    alert( "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog." );
};
$( "#foo" ).bind( "click", handler );
$( "#foo" ).unbind( "click", handler );
```

Try out this [link](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)
and [link](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-bind-and-unbind-example/)

Comment: I don't quite understand. With my code above, how to fix it ?

Comment: Wherever you are calling the Window.Open() method, just add the Unbind() method along with it, preferably before the Window.Open() method call. This will disable the mouse leave event method.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to declare your event handler like this

```
var myHandler = function(event) {
       window.location.href = "http://your-website.com";
};

$(document).bind('mouseleave', myHandler);
```

Then call this when you want to remove it from the `document`

```
$(document).unbind('mouseleave', myHandler);
```